# How to use full width on mobile devices, but keep side margins on desktop devices with bootstrap 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to keep the side margins on the page in desktop resolution (like the `.container` behavior), but in tablet and phone size use the full width of the page in bootstrap 3 (like the `.container-fluid` behavior)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your needs correctly, I don't think you are looking for ".container-fluid" behavior (they have added this back in as of v3.1), but more so you are looking to design the mobile/desktop differently.

The example will illustrate how it is being done. See it in action by adjusting your browser width.

Example here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
  <!-- Optional: clear the XS cols if their content doesn't match in height -->
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4</div>
</div>
```

Use the class prefix that suits your needs.

.col-xs-# < 768px
.col-sm-# > 768px
.col-md-# > 992px
.col-lg-# > 1200px

So say for mobile, you like the width to be 100% of the screen, but for desktop you want the 2 columns shows as one.

So you could do something like this instead:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    Some Text in box #1
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    Some Text in box #2
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it will look like on a mobile:

Some Text in box #1 (this will take up the entire line of your mobile width)
Some Text in box #2 (this will take up the entire line of your mobile width)

Assuming |<-- 12 columns -->|
On your desktop, it would more like this:

|<-------- Some Text in box #1 --------><-------- Some Text in box #2 -------->|

Because: |<-- 6 columns -->|<-- 6 columns -->|

Mobile would be more like this:

|<-------- 12 -------->|
|<-------- 12 -------->|

|<-------- Some Text in box #1 -------->|
|<-------- Some Text in box #2 -------->|

Comment: Could you elaborate on that last part? What do those pixel values mean? Are those the points where the width becomes 100%?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap 3.1 `container` becomes full width when the screen width is less than 768 pixels (smallest devices): http://www.bootply.com/121222

If you want the `container` to be become full width sooner (at some wider screen width) you can use a media query for whatever width you want to be the threshold. For example, this change it to full width at any width less that 992 pixels:

```
@media (max-width:992px) {
    .container {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/121224